# Why do my Windows computer prints invisible characters?

Tags: windows, character

Good day,

I have an issue with my Windows 10 computer, when typing some code, and compiling/testing, I sometimes have a character added to my file:

```
Character: 
Decimal code: 3
Hexadecimal code: 0x3
Java string: \u0003
```

Look like the codes/details of an End of Text character, but I'm not sure, and I do not no why it is typed with other characters in my files when coding. Do you know which character it is and how to avoid typing it by mistake?

Comment: Impossible to answer that question. What program are you typing into?

Comment: Notepad++, but it's making it in browsers and other inputs.
BTW I did reset my laptop (factory reset) just before, that's why I'm surprised to see such kind of issue-s.

Comment: Character 03 is also known as Control+C. Possibly an issue with your keyboard, if it's not just Notepad++.